# Design polygons area in coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

It happens that I'm carrying out surveys whose data can be shown directly (as if it were a map) using polar_coordinates as they are defined by the distance and angle with respect to the center.
However, some data should be represented by not simple points but surfaces, defined by the position and angle of four or more points identified by a common variable (as would happen in a normal clustering).
In the following example, I would like all the points identified with the variable "Qu" to be grouped on the same surface. The problem of calculating the surfaces can easily be tackled separately, for the purposes of the graph for the moment I am only interested in the representation.

```
library(ggplot2)

Azimut<-c(30,60,90,270,275, 45, 135, 45, 180)
Distance<-c(3,6,12,16,22, 4, 16, 18, 18)
CHR<-c(12,19,55,7,39,34,32,34,32)
Spe1<-c("Eu","Pi","Qu","Qu","Ol", "Qu", "Qu", "Qu", "Qu")
Tr1<-data.frame(Azimut,Distance, CHR, Spe1)
Tr1$Theta<-2*pi*Azimut/360

# With polar coordinates
ggplot(aes(x = (Azimut), y = Distance), data = Tr1) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 6)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 18)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360),
                     breaks = seq(0, 360, 45)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = (c(0, 18)),
                     breaks = (seq(0, 6, 18))) +
  geom_point(aes(size=CHR, fill=factor(Spe1)),shape =21,alpha = 0.7)+
  coord_polar(theta = "x")
```

That gives this result:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want points within the same group to be the vertices of a filled polygon? Should the polygon's edges curve according to the polar co-ordinates or appear visually straight?

Comment: My idea is to have cluster grouped by straight lines of a polygon. What I am trying now is to convert polar to cartesian and redo the graphic

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here. One is to calculate the curves that, when transformed to polar co-ordinates, give straight lines. The second is to convert your data to polar co-ordinates and plot normal rectilinear polygons. For several reasons, I think the second option is easier. It is even possible to use annotation layers to fake the polar axes:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = Distance * cos(Theta), y = Distance * sin(Theta)), data = Tr1) +
  geom_abline(slope = c(1000, 0, tan(pi/6), tan(pi/3), tan(-pi/3), tan(-pi/6)),
              color = 'white', linewidth = 0.5) +
  geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), 
            data = data.frame(x = 6 * sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200)),
                              y = 6 * cos(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200)))) +
  geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), 
            data = data.frame(x = 18 * sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200)),
                              y = 18 * cos(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200)))) +
  geom_path(aes(x = x, y = y), 
            data = data.frame(x = 20 * sin(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200)),
                              y = 20 * cos(seq(0, 2 * pi, length = 200))),
            col = 'white') +
  annotate("text", label = c("360/0", seq(45, 315, 45)),
           x = 20 * sin(seq(pi/2, -5*pi/4, -pi/4)),
           y = 20 * cos(seq(pi/2, -5*pi/4, -pi/4))) +
  geom_point(aes(size = CHR, fill = factor(Spe1)), shape = 21, alpha = 0.7) +
  lapply(split(Tr1, Tr1$Spe1), function(x) {
    if(nrow(x) < 4) return(NULL)
    geom_polygon(data = x[chull(x$Distance * cos(x$Theta), 
                                x$Distance * sin(x$Theta)),],
                 aes(fill = factor(Spe1), 
                     color = after_scale(scales::alpha(fill, 1))), alpha = 0.2)
  }) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'gray92', color = NA),
        plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thnaks! I think I am in the middle of it right now. I converted the coordinates to cartesian and then I started studying the geometrical issues. ANd I was also thinking to add a "fake" polar axis that can helps for the sake of my report.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the row indices of the points forming a surrounding convex hull with `chull` and use their coordinates with `geom_polygon`. With cartesian coordinates this works - but polar coordinates may give unexpected results. In case of your example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- 
  data.frame(
    Azimut = c(30,60,90,270,275, 45, 135, 45, 180),
    Distance = c(3,6,12,16,22, 4, 16, 18, 18),
    CHR = c(12,19,55,7,39,34,32,34,32),
    Spel = c("Eu","Pi","Qu","Qu","Ol", "Qu", "Qu", "Qu", "Qu")
  ) |>
  mutate(Theta =  pi * Azimut / 180)
  
## which rows of subset Spel === "Qu" form the convex hull for this subset
hull_rows <- 
  df |>
  filter(Spel == "Qu") |>
  select(Azimut, Distance) |>
  chull()

df |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(Azimut, Distance)) +
  geom_polygon(data = df[hull_rows,],
               aes(Azimut, Distance),
               fill = 'red', alpha = .5
               ) + coord_polar()
```

[image]
(kind of Debian logo ...)

Comment: Indeed Debian is everywhere, my favorite distro for 20 years, but it still is not the solution I am searching for, but this is useful, take my upvote!